# Luis why im not getting normalized value entity

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Can anybody explain me if my intent is with word `vilniuje` im getting `vilniuje` as entity and not `vilnius`?

or how can i get `vilnius` instead of `vilniuje`?
Im using node for that here is my code there im getiing entityt

```
var cityEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(results.intent.entities, "city");
```

[image: Luis entity list]

Btw im new in Ms bot framework so i dont know much :)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `vilniuje` as entity because it is the real entity that is found on your data.

But as you can see in your result, it is also giving its `resolution` as `Vilnius` in the content of LUIS Result, so you have to use this value.

```
var cityEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(results.intent.entities, "city");

if (cityEntity && cityEntity.resolution.values.length > 0) {
    // DO WHAT YOU WANT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, the entity value is the synonym or normalized string detected in the raw query, in both cases we return the normalized value in the entity resolution field:

e.g.
Entity: Family
Normalization value Synonyms
Mom Mother ,  Irina
Dad Father , Joseph

Query: Call Irina 
Type  : Family 
Value: Irina
Resolution : Mum

Hope this helps.